# Can Fluent Validation .NET determine error messages sequence

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

I use Fluent Validation .NET for validating.
Is it possible to determine error messages sequence from "RuleFor" in validation summary.

Example:

```
RuleFor(x=>x.A).NotEmpty().WithMessage("A is required.");
RuleFor(x=>x.B).NotEmpty().WithMessage("B is required.");
```

For example, How can I determine message sequence to specificly show "B is required." before "A is required".

Comment: Can you describe in details, which behavior you want to see? Same messages for different rules, or message for B, that depends on A value, or something else?

Comment: I added some more detail about question. I just want to sort the message that display on Summary Validation Message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no explicit ordering of rules inside `FluentValidationModelValidationFactory` validator queries, that means that order of error messages on server-side depends on order of rules declaration, e.g. if rule for `A` property goes before rule for `B`, then you will see in `ValidationResult` error message for `A` before `B`. But it works only for manually getting of validation result (create validator object and call `Validate` method).

After errors get into `ModelState` object - they loss their order. Thats because of `ModelStateDictionary` type, which stores objects as Dictionary, not as List.

And if we look at NDoc description of `ValidationSummary` method, we see:

> Returns an **unordered** list (ul element) of validation messages that are in the ModelStateDictionary object.

But if **client-side validation enabled** - then validation summary element appears without server call, and it's error messages order the same as order of inputs in html.

**Conclusion**
The only way to save error message order in `ViewResult` is to 'manually' use validator, call validate and manually iterate `ValidationResult` in partial view or template to create markup you need. But if you rely on client-side validation — you can just reoder inputs on form.