# Can you change the order of error messages in a validation summary?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation

Can you change the order in which error messages appear in the validation summary based on their order.

I currently have some JQuery which re-arranges panels on a page based on external input. Since the re-ordering is done with javascript on the client side it doesn't reflect the changes in position of each validator in the validation summary.

I've looked at each of the validator messages in the validation summary on the client side and there are no ID's assigned to individual error messages so organizing them that way is not possible.

Is there another method of organizing the validator messages after some switching of panels on the client side?

If not if I do this on the server side will the position of validators be reflected in the validation summary in the same order that they are displayed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30789504/html-validationsummary-how-to-set-order-of-error-messages

Comment: @maztt I believe that solution only applies to MVC, I'm using web forms